# powershell null-valued expression error while unzip

Tags: powershell

I am trying to download a zip file from S3 and unzip to a particular folder using the below script:

```
$zipfile = "myapp.zip"
$dest_loc = "C:\test\"
aws s3 cp s3://apptxtmy/$zipfile $dest_loc
$shell = New-Object -Com Shell.Application
$zip = $shell.NameSpace("$dest_loc\$zipfile")
if (!(Test-Path "C:\test\appname\")) { 
    mkdir C:\test\appname
}
$shell.Namespace("C:\test\appname\").CopyHere($zip.items())
```

But I keep on getting the below error:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>   At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\deploy.ps1:9 char:1
>   + $shell.Namespace("C:\test\appname\").CopyHere($zip.items())

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try removing the balckslash at the end of `$dest_loc = "C:\test\"`.  It is resulting in a later path of: `"C:\test\\myapp.zip"`.

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: Is the resulting full path actually valid?  The reason it is failing is that `$zip` is `$null`, which is likely because `C:\test\myapp.zip` doesn't exist.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a COM object instead of the native Syster.IO.Compression?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485723(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: because you don't always have .NET 4.5.x installed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to native Powershell commands...

You can use [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive) (if you're on PS v4+) to extract the zip file.

And [Read-S3Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Read-S3Object.html) (part of [AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/)) to get the file from S3.

[Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) can also be used to ensure you don't have issues with double slash `\\` in your paths.

```
$zipfile = "myapp.zip"
$dest_loc = "C:\test"
$appname = "appname"
$bucket = "apptxtmy"

$unzip_loc = Join-Path $dest_loc $appname
$zip_loc = Join-Path $dest_loc $zipfile

Read-S3Object -BucketName $bucket -Key $zipfile -file $zip_loc

if ((Test-Path $unzip_loc) -eq $false) { 
    New-Item $unzip_loc -ItemType Directory
}

Expand-Archive -Path $zip_loc -DestinationPath $unzip_loc
```

Comment: sorry but this is not a solution and you cannot use expand-archive prior to PowerShell 5

Comment: @McVitas prior to PS5 you need to install [Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive) manually.